# can i use c-like arrays in python instead of lists as list are slow

Tags: python, arrays, list

http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/little-deepu-and-array/

This is the problem on above link which i solved using python.
but as list are slow i am not able to pass all test cases due to time constraint, whereas when solved using arrays in c++, i passed all test cases.

**Python:**

```
n=input()
l=map(int,raw_input().split())
m=input()
for i in range(m):
    x=input()
    for j in range(n):
        if(l[j]>x):
            l[j]-=1
for i in range(n):
    print l[i],
```

**C++:**

```
int main() 
{
    int n,numCalls,x,i,j;
    long int arr[1000000];

    cin>>n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    cin>>numCalls;
    for(i=0;i<numCalls;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(arr[j]>x)
                arr[j]-=1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

Can anyone solve this problem in python efficiently so that all test-cases can be passed!!.

Comment: Check out numpy, it has arrays.

Comment: Also use the standard array library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

Comment: can you give me example how to input integer elements in arrays in python

Comment: thanks Brent Washburne:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code with one change, initializing `l` with a Python array:

```
import array

n=input()
l=array.array('l', map(int, raw_input().split()))
m=input()
for i in range(m):
    x=input()
    for j in range(n):
        if(l[j]>x):
            l[j]-=1
for i in range(n):
    print l[i],
```